# How to convert firestore collection from .get() to string using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, web, google-cloud-firestore

currently I am writing a website which will use cloud firestore as a database. To read the collection, this is my code

```
const docRef = firestore.doc("driver/D001");
firestore.collection("driver")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

It took quite long to get the result, and the result is

```
D001  =>  { contactNo: '0814444555', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Ohmygod' }
```

which is correct

But how can I to convert each the result to string and assign it to variable, so I can keep the value and show it on my website.
Or and of you guys can suggest any other way than using javascript to read the firestore collection when developing a website? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking about how to do two things:

1. serialize the document data into a string
2. use the string value elsewhere in your site

The first part depends on you want to present the data. A simple way convert the doc data to a string is to use a Template Literal and extract the fields explicitly:

```
function toString(doc) {
  let data = doc.data();
  return `${data.contactNo}, ${data.firstName}, ${data.lastName}`;
}
```

You could then convert the documents as you receive them:

```
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", toString(doc.data()));
    });
})
```

As for using this data in your website, presumably you want to hand off these values to some consumer, however that depends on the details of what you want to do with the data. For example in the body of the function you pass to forEach() you could call another function that updates some part of your document, prints to console, etc.